Isn’t ״צרות לבבי הרחיבו״ an oxymoron?
In Tehillim 25:17, David says:

צָר֣וֹת לְבָבִ֣י הִרְחִ֑יבוּ מִ֝מְּצוּקוֹתַ֗י הוֹצִיאֵֽנִי׃
My deep distress increases; deliver me from my straits.

The root ״צר״ literally translates as “narrow”. Its antonym is ״רחב״ - wide; e.g. (Tehillim 118:5):

מִֽן־הַ֭מֵּצַר קָרָ֣אתִי יָּ֑הּ עָנָ֖נִי בַמֶּרְחָ֣ב יָֽהּ׃
In distress I called on the LORD;the Lord answered me and brought me relief.

Why, then, does David lament that his “narrowness” has “widened”?
(The Alshich and the Malbim both provide a similar explanation, but I would like to hear another approach.)

Poetic wordplay?

@shmosel Perhaps. Do you have any other examples of this kind of wordplay used in Tehillim?

"צָר֣וֹת לְבָבִ֣י הִרְחִ֑יבוּ מִ֝מְּצוּקוֹתַ֗י הוֹצִיאֵֽנִי [...] The root 'צר' literally translates as 'narrow'." Except, the singular of 'צָרוֹת' is 'צָרָה/צָרַת', and the plural of 'צַר' is 'צָרֵי' (or maybe צוֹרְרֵי?).

“Awful” literally means full of awe. That doesn’t mean “awfully disrespectful” is an oxymoron. This reasoning, combined with @shmosel’s comment, form a perfect and simple explanation.
